# Adding php code to an existing code

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if( get_field('custom_printing_slider_description') ):
    echo get_field($field_name);
    endif;
```

I would like to add to the following line in between `</h3>` and `</div>`:

```
$popup .= '<div class="pps-header"><h3 class="pps-title">'.get_the_title($popup_id).'</h3></div>;
```

Adding the code directly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

- Your file should end with `.php`
- don't forget to put the PHP code between `<?php` and `?>`
- make sure the PHP interpreter is installed
- if statements look like this:

  ```
  if(#condition) {
  //#body
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like that. I think you forgot give between  **" "**.

```
$popup .= "<div class="pps-header"><h3 class="ppstitle">'.get_the_title($popup_id).'
</h3></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, it will not work because you are trying to echo inside a variable. I believe you later will show $popup somewhere. This code should work:

```html
//Add the title
$popup .= '<div class="pps-header"><h3 class="pps-title">' . get_the_title($popup_id) . '</h3>';

//If the field is there
if(get_field('custom_printing_slider_description')) {
 $popup .= get_field($field_name);  //--> add the field to $popup variable
}

//Close the open div tag
$popup .= '</div>';
```

Notice that you are validating get_field, if the condition is true, then you add the $field_name, close the div after the if statement, in case your condition is not true, you are closing tags correctly.